# Pass datepicker back to input field on change

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

How can I pass the correct formatted date into an input field when changing the Jquery datepicker?

This is my input:

```
<input type="text" class="new_ship_date" name="new_ship_date" value="<?php echo esc_attr( substr( $current_date, 0, 10 ) ); ?>">
```

This is what I tried, but when selecting a new date the input just says Invalid Date:

```
    $('#mypicker').datepicker({
    //options
    dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    minDate: new Date(dt),
    firstDay: 0,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                var nsd = new Date(dateText);
        $('.new_ship_date').val(nsd);
    },
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,

});
```

I need the format to be in yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: Hi, change `dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd"` to `dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"`

Comment: @Swati On change, the format is going into the output as "Mon Mar 08 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)". Is there a way to slim that down to what I need?

Comment: Does [this](https://jsfiddle.net/haw1rves/) showing that behaviour ?

Comment: @Swati Yeah added the same and that's what it's outputting. Can I convert that into what I need perhaps?

Comment: That fiddle doesn't show that behaviour and its happening because you have `new Date(dateText);` look at code carefully i have removed that line and only have kept `$('.new_ship_date').val(dateText);` .

Comment: @Swati Yeah I'd removed that line too but the format is still coming out like that on my. I wonder if I can add another line in there to convert the date again via jquery to make sure? So take `dateText` and convert it again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228416/discussion-between-swati-and-rob).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

$.datepicker.parseDate( format, value, options )

```js
var date = $('.from').val();   
var result = $.datepicker.formatDate("dd.mm.yy", $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', date));
$(".result").text(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
From <input type="text" class="from" value="2017-11-07">
<br><br>Result : <span class="result"></span>
```